# Explicación de código usado en un return

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente funcion que sera aplicada a :
digPow(89, 1) should return 1 since 8¹ + 9² = 89 = 89 * 1
digPow(92, 1) should return -1 since there is no k such as 9¹ + 2² equals 92 * k
digPow(695, 2) should return 2 since 6² + 9³ + 5⁴= 1390 = 695 * 2
digPow(46288, 3) should return 51 since 4³ + 6⁴+ 2⁵ + 8⁶ + 8⁷ = 2360688 = 46288 * 51
Tengo dudas acerca del codigo que usa en el return , no logro entederlo. En especifico lo que hace el '?' y ':'.

```js
function digPow(n, p) {
  var x = String(n).split("").reduce((s, d, i) => s + Math.pow(d, p + i), 0)
  return x % n ? -1 : x / n
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x % n ?` pregunta si existe un residuo

si hay entonces la salida es `-1`

en otro caso la salida es `x/n`

- para que entiendas esta parte: `-1 : x / n`

  salida en caso sea verdadero : salida en caso sea falso